# Unable to update @graphql-mesh

Tags: graphql, graphql-mesh

I have update the @graphql-mesh with to latest version and below are the packages

```
 "@graphql-mesh/config": "^6.1.0",
 "@graphql-mesh/graphql": "^0.29.12",
 "@graphql-mesh/openapi": "^0.31.2",
 "@graphql-mesh/runtime": "0.42.2",
 "@graphql-mesh/soap": "0.12.12"
```

After upgrade I got error for below function

```
import { findAndParseConfig } from '@graphql-mesh/cli';
```

findAndParseConfig is not available in latest version. Can anyone suggest from which module I can call this function or is there any alternative to do so?

Added same on github as well:

https://github.com/OpenSourceHelpCommunity/Questions/issues/109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `@graphql-mesh/cli` is not on your dependencies list.

Try adding it (`yarn add @graphql-mesh/cli`).
If error still occurs - could you provide some more info, starting with the error message?

Comment: Yup. implemented your suggestion from github. Its up now thanks.